# SSRS - SubReport

Tags: reporting-services

I have a subreport I am trying to link into my main report. The main report pulls back information from one database and the subreport pulls from another. I could use lookup, but I lose the ability to format so I was hoping to achieve this with a subreport.

I enter a date range via my parameters, and let's say I get 30 client/matter codes back. It page breaks at the end of each row, so the data for each client/matter ends up on its own report. The goal is for me to output a large number of reports based on date ranges. The subreport pulls in folder names, and just like the other information, the folders for *only* that client/matter should be on that report.

What's currently happening is on each report, it just lists ALL of the folders for ALL of the client matters on each and every report.

I've tried making the subreport an adjacent group (which you can see in the screenshot) and grouping on Client code and then matter code. I've tried making the client code and matter codes internal parameters in both reports in the hope that it help filtered. I also tried just inserting the subreport into a cell inside the matter_code group but not as a group itself.

I apologize in advance if my explanation doesn't make sense. I'm having a hard time trying to put this into words.

[image: report]

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I would assume that you have a subreport in a group but you are not passing anything through to it. Have you tried passing through parameters to the subreport that uniquely define the customer and the customer folders?

Comment: I'm passing through one parameter which is a date range. As I mentioned in my post above, "I've tried making the client code and matter codes internal parameters in both reports in the hope that it help filtered."  If there's a different way to pass those that would work, any thoughts?

Comment: The subreport itself itself needs to work independently of the main report in the first place. What I tend to do is work from there outwards. In the subreport, define the parameters needed with default values and run the report, in your case, add the date range and the client/matter codes as needed to pull the individual folder for the report. When you have this working it is just a case of making sure the correct values are plugging in to the subreport from the main report